# performance issue with Apache2 server and wso2esb

Tags: apache, wso2, wso2-esb

Am working on wso2esb and created several proxy services and using Apache 2 proxy to call this services, So every request of ESB goes through the Apache2 proxy ,After an usage of 10-15 days the performance becomes slow day by day along with all the other servers performance which are using Apache 2 server are also slow.

Tried reloading and restarting Apache server but no change in performance.

When i restarted the esb server then it was back to normal stage, Doesn't know what esb is holding and causing this performance issue.

what can be done to resolve this with out restarting the esb server.

Comment: Clearly there is nothing with your Apache2 server. Anything like exception in wsoesb log?

Comment: hi simar no exceptions in the esb even, All the services are running perfectly with out any exceptions.